# Test an array and random value PHPunit

Tags: php, arrays, unit-testing, multidimensional-array, phpunit

I have a little problem with my unit test and an array generated "randomly",

I have something looking like this :

```php
return [
 'foo' => $this->faker->sentence(),
 'bar' => [
    'baz' => $this->faker->realText(),
    'booz' => [
       'baaz' => $this->faker->title()
    ]
 ]
];
```

`$this->faker->xxx` generate random strings or whatever, but I want to test the "shape" of the array, I want to ensure I have :

foo in first children array, bar too
Bar have baz and booz at the same level and booz have a baaz in children.

But I could not find how to do that, I have tried something like this but it is not working :/

```php
$this->assertEquals([
  'foo' => \Mockery::any(),
  'bar' => [
    'baz' => \Mockery::any(),
  ],
], $class->method());
```

Maybe this is not possible and I should find a way to simply test the keys in the array?

Maybe `array_diff_key` can help me here?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694117/how-to-test-inner-arrays-with-phpunit

Comment: Thanks you @JacobMulquin, my googling power is not workin anymore I guess :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try to use the most expressive assertion. `assertEquals` is for equality, `assertTrue` for booleans. But you only want to check the structure, so `assertArrayHasKey',` assertIsString`and`assertIsArray` are your friends.

```php
$this->assertArrayHasKey($data['foo']);
$this->assertIsString($data['foo']);

$this->assertIsArray($data['bar']);
$this->assertArrayHasKey($data['bar']['baz']);
$this->assertIsString($data['bar']['baz']);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple assertions:

```
$data = $class->method();
$this->assertTrue(isset($data[‘foo’]);
$this->assertTrue(isset($data[‘bar’]);
$this->assertTrue(is_array($data[‘bar’]);
$this->assertTrue(isset($data[‘bar’][‘baz’]);
$this->assertTrue(isset($data[‘bar’][‘booz’]);
$this->assertTrue(is_array($data[‘bar’][‘booz’]);
$this->assertTrue(isset($data[‘bar’][‘booz’][‘baaz’]);
```

Comment: Yes I did that finally, helpers functions like Laravel have ->assertJsonStructure() does not fit well :/

Comment: If tone of these assertions fail you'll get the message "Failed asserting that false is true". Not very helpful.